# Question editing renders an answer invalid

Tags: discussion

it has occured to me that there are questions, for which some edits change their meaning. Changed so much, that an answer is rendered irrelevant or out of scope, even sometimes attracting downvotes. How is this properly handled? How is a user permitted to alter his/her question so much?

Comment: [Chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478) are network-wide problem.

Comment: I'm sure it is by the looks of it. I just got childishly disappointed when I saw some of my fresh new rep get diminishing in one such question! Anyway, nice to have met you, we'll be seeing each other I hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A question should never be altered at the point that any given answer is anymore valid.

If the OP notices the question didn't come out like he meant, he should ask another question. Changes that make answers invalid should be rolled back.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your answer and time. Btw, what is OP? So when I take notice of such a case, what should I do, flag the question? And would that be enough?

Comment: The OP is the user who asked the question. Just let the community handle those questions, and flag the questions that are too old to be handled from the community.

Comment: @Wtower OP literally stands for Original Poster. That's where this 2 letters came from ;) Just thought I should add that to kiamlaluno's explanation.